# How can I insert a new row, but if the combination of 2 values already exist update the row?

Tags: mysql

my table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE sample 
(
 id int auto_increment primary key, 
 W_ID varchar(20), 
 TC_ID varchar(20),
  foo varchar(20),
  bar varchar(20)
);
```

I want to insert a new row into this table, but if the combination of W_ID and TC_ID already exists, i want to update the row with the new values of 'foo' and 'bar'

I know there are a lot of similar questions on here, but i can't figure it out....

made a sample in [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07f005/18)

i am using  5.6.11-MySQL  - Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.3.25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a unique key of the combination of W_ID and TC_ID then perform your upsert on it as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE sample 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     W_ID varchar(20), 
     TC_ID varchar(20),
      foo varchar(20),
      bar varchar(20)
    );

alter table sample add constraint UNIQUE (W_ID, TC_ID);

INSERT INTO sample 
(W_ID, TC_ID,foo,bar)
VALUES ('1', '2','123','123');
INSERT INTO sample 
(W_ID, TC_ID,foo,bar)
VALUES ('2', '2','123','123');
INSERT INTO sample 
(W_ID, TC_ID,foo,bar)
VALUES ('3', '2','123','123');
INSERT INTO sample 
(W_ID, TC_ID,foo,bar)
VALUES ('1', '4','123','123');
INSERT INTO sample 
(W_ID, TC_ID,foo,bar)
VALUES ('2', '3','123','123');

INSERT INTO sample 
(W_ID, TC_ID,foo,bar)
VALUES ('1', '2','123','123')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
`foo` = 'newFoo';
```

your results would look like:

```
ID  W_ID    TC_ID    FOO    BAR
1   1   2            newFoo 123
2   2   2            123    123
3   3   2            123    123
4   1   4            123    123
5   2   3            123    123
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add unique constraint on the two columns you'll be able to use [on duplicate key update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax.
Adding an unique constrain should be something like that:

```
alter table table_name add unique index index_name(col1, col2);
```

You'll find more details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: the two columns are not unique by itself... only the combination of the 2 should unique.

Comment: thnx ,my responds was too fast :)